# Stomp Socket not working in tomcat cluster having 2 instances. I am broadcasting messages using simpMessagingTemplate. This is Not chat application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, websocket, cluster-computing, stomp

Stomp web socket is working nice in tomcat single instance. But when two instances are up it is not working. I am using spring boot application and VueJS frontEnd.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/connect-to-websocket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

}
```

and after some action i am using template like this.

```
this.template.convertAndSend("/Auction/currentPrice",auctionDetailsSocketEntity);
```

so who ever subscribe to /Auction/currentPrice will be receiving this data.

I AM ONLY BROADCASTING MESSAGE WHO EVER SUBSCRIBE TO THIS.

This is working fine with one Instance. But two instances are up this is not working. How to fix it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@RajaSekhar Chodavarapu,try this ...

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        }
        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/connect-to-ebsocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this.  just for clarification config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic"); here i have to give /Auction and destinationPrefix as /currentPrice am i correct?

Comment: you need send like this this.template.convertAndSend("/Auction/currentPrice",auctionDetailsSocketEntity);

Comment: enableSimpleBroker("/topic")---->enableSimpleBroker("/Auction")

Comment: thank you and while subscribeing this from vue js or connecting to socket should i refer to /app any where in client side. This destination prefix is any where refered ??